# Install WordPress: installation script not running

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

**WordPress (Version 4.9.1)**

**nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)**

I'm trying to run WordPress locally for the first time.
I follow this instruction: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

I've got stuck at Step 5: Run the Install Script.

I've downloaded it and extracted to /var/www/wordpress.

Below is nginx conf.

**site.conf**

```
server {
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # permalinks
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

When I visit http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php, I get an empty page.

Namely:

**Request headers**

```
GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

**Response headers**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 14 Dec 2017 13:51:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip

Nginx error log is empty.

Nginx access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2017:16:51:16 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
```

Well, WordPress seems to have responded. But no installation process seems to have started.

Could you help me here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did all well here!
You just firing a wrong url. Fire following url and check whether it is working or not.
`http://localhost/wordpress/`
Thank you!

Comment: No. Result is the same. Well, by the way, I've prepared a hello_world.php. And I can't run it from that folder. It returns Content-Type: text/html and shows nothing. And WordPress's index.php also doesn't work.

Comment: Strange! make sure all services are running and try this url `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin` where `wordpress` is a name of folder in `/var/www/wordpress` directory. Also check the if the WordPress files are not in sub `wordpress` folder like in `/var/www/wordpres/wordpress`

Comment: /var/www/wordpres is a root directory. For example there is readme.html in that directory. If I type localhost/readme.html, readme shows. So, no php file runs.

Comment: As for wordpress/wordpress - no. I have checked. There is something wrong with fastcgi .